Can axes $x$ and $y$ be rotated to eliminate the crossed product terms in a cubic form?
I've just learned that it is posible to rotate the axes $x$ and $y$ to obtain the axes $x'$ and $y'$ such that the quadratic form $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2$$ converts to $$\lambda _1x'^2+\lambda _2y'^2$$ So, is it possible to do the same to the form $$ax^3+bx^2y+cxy^2+y^3$$?

This is essentially solving the cubic equation. You will have to depress the cubic and make Vieta's substitution.
